# PHP Nested loops where values are the key to the next level of the array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, nested

I'm relatively new to PHP and I hope you can help me solve my problem.  I am selecting out data from a database into an array for timekeeping.  Ultimately, I would like to calculate the total number of hours spent on a project for a given customer.

Here is the code to populate a multi-dimensional array:
...

```
foreach ($record as $data) {  
  $mArray = array();  
  $name = $data['user'];  
  $customer = $data['customer'];  
  $project = $data['project'];  
  $hours = $data['hours'];  

  $mArray[$name][$customer][$project] += $hours;  
}
```

...

I would now like to iterate over $mArray to generate an xml file like this:

...

```
foreach ($mArray as $username) {
  foreach ($mArray[$username] as $customerName) {
    foreach ($mArray[$username][$customerName] as $project ) {
        echo '<'.$username.'><'.$customerName.'><'.$project.'><hours>'.
           $mArray[$username][$customerName][$project].'</hours></'.$project.'>
           </'.$customerName.'></'.$username.'>';
    }
  }
}
```

This nested foreach doesn't work.  Can someone give me a couple of tips on how to traverse this structure?  Thank you for reading!

UPDATE:
Based on the comments I've received so far (and THANK YOU TO ALL), I have:

```
foreach ($mArray as $userKey => $username) {
  foreach ($mArray[$userKey] as $customerKey => $customerName) {
    foreach ($mArray[$userKey][$customerKey] as $projectKey => $projectName) {
      echo '<name>'.$userKey.'</name>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<customerName>'.$customerKey.'</customerName>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<projectName>'.$projectKey.'</projectName>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<hours>'.$mArray[$userKey][$customerKey][$projectKey].'</hours>';
      echo "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

This is now only providing a single iteration (one row of data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foreach syntax is `foreach($array as $value)`. You're trying to use those values as array keys, but they're not values - they're the child arrays. What you want is either:

```
foreach($mArray as $username) {
   foreach($username as ...)
```

or

```
foreach($mArray as $key => $user) {
   foreach($mArray[$key] as ...)
```

Comment: I'm getting closer.  I chose your option 2.  But now, I'm only getting the first set of data.

Comment: probably would be better to use something like `foreach($mArray as $username=>$customer){ foreach($customer as $customerName=>$projects){ foreach($project as $project=>$hours){ ...` then you have access to the keys as $username, $customerName, $project and the $hours

Comment: make sure you use different names for all your `$x => $y` variables, or your inner loops will overwrite whatever the outer loops are doing.

Comment: Yes.  My syntax is correct now, but I'm only getting one row:

Comment: foreach ($mArray as $userKey => $username) {
  foreach ($mArray[$userKey] as $customerKey => $customerName) {
    foreach ($mArray[$userKey][$customerKey] as $projectKey => $projectName) {
      echo '<name>'.$userKey.'</name>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<customerName>'.$customerKey.'</customerName>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<projectName>'.$projectKey.'</projectName>';
      echo "\n";
      echo '<hours>'.$mArray[$userKey][$customerKey][$projectKey].'</hours>';
      echo "\n";
    }
  }
}

Comment: IT WORKS!  On the first loop where I assign and aggregate the hours, I reinitialize the mArray.  Wow, bad on me.